# Declaring a structure pointer as a return type for a function

Tags: c++

The following code gives an error-**"DECLARATION SYNTAX ERROR"**
Here node is a structure(for a linked list)
[Forgive me if this is a stupid question ,as I am new to programming]

```
node * enter(int n)
{
ptr=new node;
ptr->info=n;
ptr->next=NULL;
return ptr;
}
```

FULL CODE-

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main()
{
    clrscr();
    struct node {
        int info;
        node* next;
    } * ptr, *y, *save, *start;
    void insert(node*);
    node* enter(int);
    void display(node*);
    start = NULL;
    int inf;
    cout << "Enter INFO:";
    cin >> inf;
    y = enter(inf);
    insert(y);
    cout << "display:\n";
    display(start);
    getch();
}

node* enter(int n)
{
    ptr = new node;
    ptr->info = n;
    ptr->next = NULL;
    return ptr;
}
void insert(int* m)
{
    if (start == NULL) {
        start = m;
    }
    else {
        save = start;
        start = m;
        m->next = save;
    }
}

void display(node* l)
{
    while (l != NULL) {
        cout << l->info << "->";
        l = l->next;
    }
    cout << "\nOVER";
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160116/discussion-on-question-by-adarsh-m-declaring-a-structure-pointer-as-a-return-typ).

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is you are declaring node and ptr inside main. Your function definition for enter and the rest of your functions will not see the declarations inside main(). You need to move

```
struct node {
    int info;
    node* next;
} * ptr, *y, *save, *start;
```

to before int main() to fix this issue.